# BuildUrlFromExpression inside of HTML - getting 404 error from link

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to build a link that will direct the user to an MVC page when they click it.  Currently I have:

```
HTMLTable.AppendLine("<td class=\"team\"> " + tournament.TournamentRoundMatches[col][effective_match_id].competitorId1 + "<a href=\"<% =Html.BuildUrlFromExpression<CompetitionController>(c => c.Details(83)) %>\">" + "  update" + "</a>" + "</td>");
```

But this just results in a 404 error, with the following link generated:

```
localhost:52313/Tournament/Details/%3C%%20=Html.BuildUrlFromExpression%3CCompetitionController%3E(c%20=%3E%20c.Details(83))%20%%3E
```

My controller method looks like this:

```
[Authorize]
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var competition = Competition.getCompetitionById(id);

        return View(competition);
    }
```

Does anyone see what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: why not use `@Html.ActionLink()` method ?

Comment: It seems like I don't have access to that - is there some way I can include something that will allow me to use that?  I've used that several times in my .cshtml files, but I can't figure out how to access it within my <Controller>.cs files.

Comment: You need to separate your presentation from your business logic. As Yasser stated, the `@Html.ActionLink()` is what you're looking for. Since the `@Html` helpers are only be available to you in the view pages, why not format the URL within the controller, and then pass the URL to the model for the view? Do you have a model for the view you're trying to work with?